# No install option, only source code

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. Trying to install new software but I see only use the source code in Ubuntu software center. There is no install option. And I am trying to install few plugins for browser its not working. I tried using WiFi as well as wired connection.

Tried following things after reading same kind of problems on net-
1.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

2.
system-> administration-> software sources  could not find this path.

3.
`sudo apt-get update` then again tried

None of these helped me.

Any suggestion would be very thankful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: What new software (from where?) do you try to install? Did you download something?

Comment: *"I see only use the source code in Ubuntu software center"* I'm absolutely sure that you **do not** see only source code in the USC. You see free (as freedom) software. USC don't download source code of packages, only CLI utils do this.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only source code, you have to compile it on yourself's.

Download the source code, open a terminal and `cd` to the download directory. (If it's an archive, extract it first.) Now use the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

If everything goes fine, the program should be installed.

*Software Sources* is to include other PPA's, not to install the software itself.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I tried what you said. When I enter make following message appeared - make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: In addition to the above problem, I am not able to create ubuntu one and ubuntu software center accounts as captcha is not loading at all. How to solve this problem

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself a bit unclearly: You have to `cd` *into* the direcory you downloaded. And sorry, there isn't a ` abfter configure. To your Captcha problem: Do websites load much faster than the Captcha?

Comment: I am going in ti the director by using the command cd then started doing the process. But its saying unable to find package.

Comment: my internet is pretty fast for browsing, but these captcha are not at all loading